# I need to delete rows which are selected in a datagridview from SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lh26n.png)

I have a datagridview with a query result from a SQL SeErver database and I inserted a new column to my datatable using

```
main.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Selector", typeof(bool)));
```

which is a checkbox cell for each row.

I want to delete the selected/checked rows from database.

Sorry for my bad English

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I need to delete the selected rows from the sql database using datagrideview (the selected / checked rows only)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your entities should have a unique ID.
For example:

```
public class client{
    public long Id { get;set; }
    public string Username { get;set; }
    public string Password { get;set; }
}
```

Your query could look like this (pseudo code not tested):

```
DELETE FROM
    Clients
WHERE Id IN (4,5,7)
```

You take all Ids from selected Clients and put them into the query

Comment: I'm glad I could help you. If my answer was the solution please don't forget to mark it as correct answer.